# How can I insert extra commits using git replace?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

What I'm trying to do is add one or more extra commits in between two other historical commits. I could do this with `git rebase` however this only works in simple cases - it is completely unpractical for large or complex repos (as any conflicts have to be re-resolved). Hence I'm forced to used `git replace` in this case.

Given this repo:

```
$ git log --all --graph --oneline
* 7c12005 (HEAD -> rewrite) commit 1_edit
| * 5d3e705 (master) commit 5
| * 662f654 commit 4
| * 9d45a4e commit 3
| * e374cd1 commit 2
|/  
* a054d47 commit 1
```

To reproduce it:

```
git init 
for i in {1..5}; do
  echo $i > "$i.txt"
  git add "$i.txt"
  git commit -m "commit $i"
done

git checkout -b rewrite HEAD~4

i="1_edit"
echo $i > "$i.txt"
git add "$i.txt"
git commit -m "commit $i"
```

I now want to move commit 2,3,4,5 ontop of `7c12005`. I could accomplish this with:

```
git checkout master
git rebase rewrite
```

However how do I do something similar with `git replace`? When I tried that with `git replace --graft -f master~4 rewrite` I get this weird result:

```
$ git log --oneline master
5d3e705 (HEAD -> master) commit 5
662f654 commit 4
9d45a4e commit 3
e374cd1 commit 2
a054d47 (replaced) commit 1
7c12005 (rewrite) commit 1_edit
```

I find it weird because I expect it to go:

```
...
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1_edit
commit 1
```

Even stranger (`commit 1` and `commit 1_edit` vanishes) is if I add `--graph`:

```
git log --oneline --graph master 
 * b4595ea (master) commit 5
 * ccdf08c commit 4
 * e6272c3 commit 3
 * 81e6eb7 commit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do `git replace --graft -f master~3 rewrite` instead where `master~3` is  `commit 2`. In other words the command would replace `commit 2` with another `commit 2` but which had a different parent.

I don't understand the logic or operation when `master~4` (`commit 1`) is referenced instead. I would think it would replace `commit 1` (which is root - no parent), with `commit 1 edit` (which has 1 parent). I think this might be a bug or edge case.

Comment: The doc says that `--graft <commit> [<parent>…​]` creates a copy of `commit` with `parent` being its new parent. It seems to me `--graft -f master~4 rewrite` did just that - a copy of `commit 1` with `commit 1 edit` as parent?

Comment: But it's missing the parent? `commit 1_edit` should have `commit 1` as it's parent.  Also it's not shown if I do the `--graph`. It looks like the graph/tree has been broken in some way by this operation. Maybe because it's self referential.